# how to Log out from ftp server?

Tags: networking, server, ftp

Guys i'm using vsftpd server and logged in using my local user account. But i want to log out from the ftp server and there is no option of log out there. Can anyone help me....?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to get help which commands you can use just type:

```
help    to request a list of all available FTP commands
```

for a quit:

```
bye to exit the FTP environment (same as quit)
quit    to exit the FTP environment (same as bye)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe concider the command

```
close
```

which results in

```
ftp> close
221 Goodbye.
ftp>
```